# Touch on UIWebview Hide/Unhide inputAccessoryView randomaly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, html, uiwebview

I am adding a UIWebview like -

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"https://www.google.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
UIWebView *playerView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
playerView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
[playerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[playerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 400)];
[playerView loadRequest:requestObj];
[playerView setHackishlyHidesInputAccessoryView:YES];
[self.view addSubview:playerView];
```

**And a input accessory view -**

```
- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return true;
}


- (UIView *)inputAccessoryView {

    UIView *playerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [playerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [playerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 50)];
    return playerView;
}
```

Now issue is that, when i touch on webview page any where, accessory view some time hide and unhide.

I want to show accessory. It should not hide in anyway. Any idea?

Comment: UIWebView does not allow to customize the `inputAccessoryView` without using magic. Just simply change the `customInputAccessoryView` property to switch to another view. Inspiration from: https://gist.github.com/bjhomer/2048571

Comment: `UIWebView` has been deprecated; if you are developing for iOS8 or higher, consider switching to `WKWebView`.